# Is this function surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this function $f:M_n(K) \rightarrow M_n(K)$ where $K$ is a field and $M_n(K)$ is the set of all $n \times n$ matrices over $K$. $ f(A)=A^*$ where $A^*$ is the adjoint of A(adjugate). Is this function surjective? If yes, how can I prove this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: By $A^\ast$ do you mean the matrix with the property that $AA^\star=\det A\cdot I$?

Comment: It's clearly bijective for $n=1,2$ (in fact it's its own inverse). For $n\ge3$, it's definitely not injective: any matrix with two zero rows, say, is taken to the zero matrix. That makes me suspect it's not surjective either (and in fact proves it if $K$ is finite).

Comment: @GregMartin: How can i prove that this function isn't surjective for n>2, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a way to answer the question: it turns out that for $A\in M_n(K)$,
$$
\mathop{\rm rank}(\mathop{\rm adj}(A)) = \begin{cases}
n, &\text{if } \mathop{\rm rank}(A)=n, \\
1, &\text{if } \mathop{\rm rank}(A)=n-1, \\
0, &\text{if } \mathop{\rm rank}(A)\le n-2.
\end{cases}
$$
This shows that the adjugate function is not surjective when $n\ge3$, since the adjugate matrix never has rank $2$, for example.

To prove the above fact, here's a sketch:

- If $A$ is invertible (equivalent to rank $n$) then $\mathop{\rm adj}(A)$ is also invertible.
- If $A$ has rank $n-1$, then at least one of its $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ minors is invertible, so $\mathop{\rm adj}(A)$ is not the zero matrix. On the other hand, $A\mathop{\rm adj}(A) = 0$, so the range of $\mathop{\rm adj}(A)$ is contained in the one-dimensional null space of $A$.
- If $A$ has rank at most $n-2$, then none of its $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ minors are invertible, so $\mathop{\rm adj}(A)$ is the zero matrix.